# Add mp3 file to java

Tags: java, mp3

[I tried to add music to my java program on jgrasp. 
When I run the code, I'm getting an gui that
 displays: "error". I was wondering how to fix 
 my code so that it plays my downloaded mp3 file. 
The following image is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCxsZ.png)

Comment: Post all code and errors here directly as text as an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the message box which merely displays `Error` because that is what your code is told to display when an error occurs. I have to say....it's not a very informative description of what the error might be which is rather sad. Do yourself a favor and instead of having just **"Error"** in your JOptionPane Message Box dialog try placing (at the very least) **e.getMessage()** which will give a more precise indication of the problem, for example:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
```

It doesn't matter if you are a beginner Java programming, if you are going to embark on a task to write code in order to play MP3 files then you should at the very least learn how to deal with exceptions (errors). These exceptions actually do help you towards success with your project, so receiving them in detail and taking action to correct the issues presented ensures a trouble free User experience.

Now, if you have done what was asked and modified your JOptionPane then run your application you will have most likely received a message something like this:

> Could not create Audio Stream from Input Stream.

Well...that's a little more informative towards the problem which is the fact that AudioStream does not support MP3 files...bummer. WAV files yes but MP3 files NO. No  reason to give up however since there are alternatives:

1. Convert your MP3 files to WAV which AudioStream can work with. You
   can probably do this online at [Media IO](https://www.media.io/);
2. Use JavaFX and the *javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer* class. You can find an [example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Playmp3file.htm);
3. Use a third party library like
   [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html) by JavaZOOM
   which makes this task extremely easy and works pretty good. Yes,
   it's old but it still does work. There are several third party
   libraries available so that your Java application can play MP3 audio
   files, just google for them.

> **Using JLayer To Play MP3 Audio Files In 8 Easy Steps:**

No... that's not a plug for JLayer. There are **lots** of examples available out there to show you how to use the JLayer library but I will quickly show you how you can accomplish this task:

1. First, download the JLayer **zip** archive. You can get the [latest version
   here](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html) and unzip it;
2. Now copy and paste the `jl1.0.1.jar` library file (located in the
   root directory of the unzipped archive) somewhere that is safe.
   Wherever you keep all your 3rd Party Java Libraries;
3. Start a new Java Application project in your particular Java IDE and
   name it PlayMP3;
4. Add a new Class which will contain a main() method to you project
   and also name it PlayMP3. The NetBeans IDE does this automatically when you create your Java Application project using the New Project wizard and the **Create Main Class** option is check marked;
5. Apply the `jl1.0.1.jar` library to your Project within your Java
   IDE. Use whatever method required by your particular IDE to do this;
6. Copy/Paste the following Imports to your new PlayMP3 class:

   ```
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
   import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
   ```
7. Copy/Paste the following code into your new PlayMP3 class **main()**
   method:

   ```
   try {
       // Try With resources used here to auto close the FileInputStream
       try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\PathTo\\YourSong.mp3")) {
           Player player = new Player(fis);
           System.out.println("YourSong.mp3 is now Playing....");
           player.play();
           System.out.println("YourSong.mp3 is now FINISHED Playing!");
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   catch (JavaLayerException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
8. Make sure your volume is up. Run the Project Application. Wait a second or two for your song to
   stream in.

As a side note, your MP3 playing should be done within its own thread so as not to tie up the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) otherwise your application code won't continue once the play() method is called, at least not until the song has finished.